# Ruby on Rails form requires another model to have certain entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, validation, null

Please keep in mind I'm learning as I go in building this Rails app.

I have 2 models in my app, Deployment and Service. Services have many deployments, and each deployment belongs to a service. In the deployments model I have attributes :service_name and :service_id, where :service_id is the foreign key.

I want to make it so that the form for creating new deployments has a field for :service_name, but not :service_id, since that's more intuitive.

This is how I'm trying to accomplish it in my deployments controller.

```
def create
    @name = params[:deployment][:service_name]
    @service = Service.find_by_name(@name)

    **if @service.nil?
        render :action => "new" , notice:'Service name (case sensitive) not found!'**
    else 
        @deployment = @service.deployments.new(params[:deployment])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @deployment.save
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Deployment was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @service, status: :created, location: @service}
      else
        format.html { redirect_to @service, notice: 'Please enter all necessary fields.' }
        format.json { render json: @deployment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
```

This is all fine and dandy ONLY as long as whatever the user submits for :service_name exists in my table for Services. Otherwise, I get the following error because @service will be null.

So Rails experts, what's the best way to deal with this error? Right now I have that rudimentary if statement (bolded), but it doesn't do what I intended. Thanks!

```
NoMethodError in Deployments#create

Showing C:/ruby_training/ServiceRegistry/app/views/deployments/_form.html.erb where line #1 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
Extracted source (around line #1):

1: <%= form_for(@deployment) do |f| %>
2:   <% if @deployment.errors.any? %>
3:     <div id="error_explanation">
4:       <h2><%= pluralize(@deployment.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this deployment from being saved:</h2>
Trace of template inclusion: app/views/deployments/new.html.erb

Rails.root: C:/ruby_training/ServiceRegistry

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/views/deployments/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_deployments__form_html_erb___545233454_35802348'
app/views/deployments/new.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_deployments_new_html_erb__57703416_31561704'
app/controllers/deployments_controller.rb:56:in `create
```

'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that, on validation failure, you are not setting a `@deployment` variable, but it's attempting to access it in the view (because you have that `render action: 'new'` in the controller).

```
@name = params[:deployment][:service_name]
@service = Service.find_by_name(@name)

if @service.nil?
    @deployment = Deployment.new(params[:deployment]) # Guessing, but this is probably what you want.
    render(:action => "new" , notice:'Service name (case sensitive) not found!')
    return  # Added this so we don't accidentally try rendering twice
else 
    @deployment = @service.deployments.new(params[:deployment])
end
```

Edit: Also I noticed that you're missing some `end`s in your code, not sure if that was an oversight.  Must have been since that would cause a different error entirely.

Comment: I like this answer. Not what I was looking for specifically, but it works. Thanks!

Comment: One more thing--any recommendations for a good starting point (ie tutorial) for working with HTTP api requests in rails?

Comment: That belongs in a question of it's own ;)  But I might look into either the `HTTParty` gem or the `json_builder` gem, depending on if you want to access an external API, or act as one, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If I am reading this correctly you want to redirect them to a different page to create the service if it's not already in the database?

I'm not sure how you have setup your routes, but if you are using

```
resources :services
```

You could do something like

```
redirect_to new_service_url
```

inside of the if instead of your render statement.

[more on redirecting in rails](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html)

Comment: I don't think that's what he wants.  It's more like a *validation failure* where he'd want the form to re-populate with the entered data, but show an error message so you could correct the one field.  I would argue he's doing the validation check in the wrong place (It should be checked in a model somewhere instead of the controller).

Comment: nzifnab is correct. I'm not sure how to validate in the model, since the validation depends on whether there the :service_name exists in another table (Services)